# Network being flooded with TCP Junk

Tags: networking, lan, wireshark, tcp

I've been using Wireshark to check out the traffic on my home network. Fairly recently, I started getting a bunch of junk generated constantly. I've been unable to find out the cause, as virus/spyware scans have done nothing and there doesn't seem to be much definite information online.

Here's an example of what Wireshark reports:

`192.168.1.103  192.168.1.1 TCP 63187 > park-agent [ACK] Seq=669 Ack=208 Win=17312 Len=0`

192.168.1.103 is my computer, 192.168.1.1 is the router. The park-agent port appears to be 5421. I downloaded TCPView to see if it could help me find the the source, but I got some pretty vague answers:

`[System Process]   0   TCP kchaloux-pc.ne.rr.com   63267   192.168.1.1 5431    TIME_WAIT`

I can't query it for any more information than that. I've tried ending the process from within TCPView but it just seems to pop back up. Does anybody know if there's a known cause behind this behavior?

I'm currently running Windows Vista (home).

Comment: Have you tried running "netstat -b" as administrator? What does it report?

Comment: Disinfect your PC, see this...http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Windows 7?  Try disabling the "IP Helper" service and see if it goes away.  This is assuming you're not using IPv6 in any way.

Comment: Running Windows Vista. Sorry, I should've specified in my main comments. Updating. Is this still relevant for the Vista OS?

Comment: I believe it is.